# Conjecture about chordal graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, chordal-graphs

I came up with the following conjecture: Let $G$ be a planar, biconnected chordal graph. Then there always exists a pair of adjacent vertices that have the same degree.

Can someone find a counter example?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It is hard to determine where the difficulties lie without more description.

Answer (score 5):

Start from a clique on vertices $\{t,u,v,w\}$ and add the following vertices:

1. $x$ adjacent to $u$ and $w$;
2. $y$ adjacent to $v$ and $w$;
3. $z$ adjacent to $v$ and $w$.

This is chordal because we start with a chordal graph ($K_4$) and added new vertices whose neighborhoods are cliques in the previous graph.

It is biconnected because we started from a biconnected graph ($K_4$) and added new vertices with at least $2$ neighbors every time.

It is planar: it's a subgraph of [this planar graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=19174).

The degrees of $t,u,v,w,x,y,z$ are $3,4,5,6,2,2,2$, and none of $x,y,z$ are adjacent to each other.

Comment: I didn't realize that would be a chordal graph. I meant planar graphs with only triangular faces. Can you then still find a counterexample?

Comment: It would then be easier to say "Apollonian network" than "planar, biconnected chordal graph with only triangular faces" :) It is still possible to find a counterexample in that case, if you keep going far enough.

Comment: Please review [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) and [What is a PSQ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854).